# AWS MSK setting advertised listeners

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk, confluent-kafka-python

I am trying to set the advertised.listeners config of my MSK cluster. However, I am getting the following error back:

> requirement failed: inter.broker.listener.name must be a listener name defined in advertised.listeners

I am not sure what this error means. I have tried searching for it but nothing comes up.
I have all my VPC related config setup. I am able to read the topic names and other configuration from the cluster.

I am using the Admin client of python's confluent_kafka module.

Here is the code:

```
import confluent_kafka.admin
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient, ConfigResource

a = AdminClient({'bootstrap.servers': '<server>:<port>'})
print(a.list_topics(timeout=5).topics) # Confirm connection

resources = list()
resources.append(ConfigResource(restype='BROKER',name='<broker_id', set_config={'advertised.listeners':'REPLICATION://<server>:<port>'}))
returned_futures = a.alter_configs(resources)
```

Comment: inter.broker.listener.name is a Broker config that also needs set, and needs to be a protocol of the advertised listeners

Comment: @OneCricketeer I can't change this config dynamically for my MSK cluster. Is this something I need to define in the cluster config during startup?

Comment: You don't need to change it. You can lookup the current value, and ensure the advertised listeners contains that protocol

Comment: @OneCricketeer Got it. That worked. Thanks. Another quick question. In the inter.broker.listener.name I am only seeing REPLICATION_SECURE. Shouldn't it include REPLICATION, CLIENT, CLIENT_SECURE as well? My clusters encryption info is set to TLS_PLAINTEXT

Comment: It can only be a single value

Comment: Hi, How can i get the `<broker_id` of MSK?